# iCal (10.6.8) and Google Calendar - issues sending invites

Tags: google-calendar, calendar.app

I have a user with a strange problem. Their Google calendars sync fine in iCal, their Me contact in AddresBook is properly set to their gmail address. The people she is sending invites to are usually in the AddressBook, but not always.

When she creates an event with attendees, some get sent but others show an exclamation point next to the username (email address) and are never sent. The addresses this happens to are not always the same and the same address is sent to from some events but not others.

Of course there is no error message, I have not been able to identify relevant information in the Console logs and I am having trouble finding people with a similar problem...

Anyone's thoughts or suggestions will be most welcome.

And of course, should I find a solution, I will share it.